# 7000+ wordpress pages now edit page not working

Tags: wordpress

I am creating listing pages from the MRIS database, I have reached 7000+ pages and my edit page always comes up blank. I am getting a 500 internal server error on my post.php

Would this many pages cause such an issue?

Comment: For an internal server error it is good to check the server logs for errors.

Comment: where would I find those?

Comment: When you use shared hosting the logs a usually available in the admin panel of your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is designed to handle millions upon millions of posts, I hardly think your 7000 would cause an issue. Most likely a plugin or some other code that's trying to alter the post editor functionality is breaking the script.

Comment: Would server memory limits cause this issue?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. That could definitely be one of many different possible issues. But it's better to find a log and understand what exactly is causing the error before trying to compensate or correct for a particular case.